# SQL запрос с NULL в WHERE

Tags: sql

Всем привет. Есть таблица categories, в ней есть родительские категории, т.е. те, в которых `parent_id = NULL`. Почему следующий запрос возвращает 0 строк?

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = NULL
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NULL` - это "специальное" значение, которое по смыслу схоже с "неопределённое значение".

```
 NULL != NULL
```

т.к. одно "неопределенное значение" не обязательно равно другому "неопределенному значению", поэтому в стандарте SQL существуют конструкции `IS NULL`, `IS NOT NULL`, `COALESCE(...)` и подобные им.

Надо использовать `IS NULL` / `IS NOT NULL`:

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id IS NULL
```

**UPDATE:** ["доходчивое" определение значения NULL от @Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743727/sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%81-null-%d0%b2-where/743729#comment1139444_743729):

Я обычно предлагаю использовать другой эквивалент: `фиг знает`. Тогда объяснение хотя бы становится логичным: "Равно ли первое `фиг знает` второму `фиг знает`?" или "Равно ли значение `Х` значению `фиг знает`?" (тут вместо `Х` подставляется число, строка, дата или переменная). Правильный ответ очевиден: а фиг знает.

Comment: Спасибо большое :)

Comment: @Alexxosipov [если ответ вам помог, отметьте его решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev отметить можно только спустя некоторое время

Comment: *которое по смыслу схоже с "неопределённое значение"* Я обычно предлагаю использовать другой эквивалент: *фиг знает*. Тогда объяснение хотя бы становится логичным: "Равно ли первое *фиг знает* второму *фиг знает*?" или "Равно ли значение Х значению *фиг знает*?" (тут вместо Х подставляется число, строка, дата или переменная). Правильный ответ очевиден: а *фиг знает*...

Comment: @Akina очень доходчиво :D

Comment: @Akina, да, действительно - очень доходчиво и показательно - спасибо! Добавил в ответ...

Answer (score 3):

Дополню, что в MS SQL Server есть возможность управлять этим поведением `NULL` в предикатах с помощью директивы `SET ANSI_NULLS ON/OFF`, пример:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;
IF NULL = NULL
    PRINT 'TRUE';
ELSE
PRINT 'FALSE';

SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
IF NULL = NULL
    PRINT 'TRUE';
ELSE
PRINT 'FALSE';

===================
>TRUE
>FALSE
```

---

Следует учитывать, что дальнейшее использование директивы [не рекомендуется](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188048(v=sql.90).aspx):

> В будущей версии параметр SQL Server ANSI_NULLS всегда будет иметь
>   значение ON, а приложения, явно присваивающие ему значение OFF, будут
>   вызывать ошибку. Избегайте использования этой возможности в новых
>   разработках и запланируйте изменение существующих приложений, в
>   которых она применяется.

*<sub>Хотя обещают это они уже не один год, угрозу свою пока что не воплотили :)</sub>*