# Соответствует ли NULL пустому множеству?

Tags: sql

Соответствует ли NULL пустому множеству {}? В английском языке empty set можно назвать как null set. Если NULL не то же самое, то отличия в том, что NULL не является множеством и не является пустым значением. Если рассматривать, что NULL означает отсутствие, неизвестность информации, то это совпадает со значением пустого множества.

Comment: [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743727/sql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81-null-%D0%B2-where)

Comment: NULL - это псевдозначение. Если оно присутствует в множестве, то множество не пустое.

Comment: Данный вопрос без/вне контекста имеет мало смысла. Я бы не стал рассматривать NULL как множество. NULL - это, скорее, __единственное__ неопределённое значение. Как я уже сказал ранее, данная дискуссия не имеет смысла вне контекста. Если вы хотите проверить является ли множество пустым средствами SQL то задайте конкретный вопрос, иначе вы рискуете получить чисто теоретические ответы, которые в реальной жизни бесполезны или не будут работать так, как вы себе представляете

Comment: Есть ли какой-то практический пример, для чего именно вам это понадобилось?